# Saving images to user's phone and tracking the progress

Tags: swift

I am trying to figure out how to implement progress bar to track saving images to user's phone. is there any way to see progress of it?

So far I got this code, which downloads all the needed images. I have track bar and download image button in my custom cell, so I created a delegate and sent info to my main tableviewcontroller. Here I am trying to write the function.

```
extension WelcomeViewController: ImageCellDelegate{

func downloadImages() {
    var indexedImages: URL!
    //
    for index in 0..<infoForCells.count{
        indexedImages = infoForCells[index].urls.thumb
        
        do{
            let imageUrl = indexedImages
            let imageData = try Data (contentsOf: imageUrl!)
            let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
            

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "Your wonderful image has been saved", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: What's the point of doing that?  Are you writing terabytes of data to the disk?

Comment: test task for a company...